# am develop for stock management project. but it show for Conversion from string "update product set quantityavail" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net

```
Protected Sub Button6_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click

a = "insert into sales values('" + TextBox15.Text + "','" + TextBox22.Text + "','" + TextBox16.Text + "','" + TextBox17.Text + "','" + TextBox18.Text + "','" + TextBox19.Text + "','" + TextBox20.Text + "','" + TextBox21.Text + "','" + Label13.Text + "','" + Label18.Text + "')"

cmd = New SqlCommand(a, con)    
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()
MsgBox("insert successfully")
Dim s As Integer
s = TextBox20.Text
a = "update product set quantityavailable=quantityavailable - '" + s + "' where productid='" + TextBox15.Text + "'"
cmd = New SqlCommand(a, con)
con.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cmd.Dispose()
con.Close()
MsgBox("update successfully")
End Sub
```

Comment: am use a = "update product set quantityavailable=quantityavailable - 1 where productid='" + TextBox15.Text + "'" . it execute properly but  a = "update product set quantityavailable=quantityavailable - '"+ s+"'  where productid='" + TextBox15.Text + "'"  show this error how to solve that error

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please read the help pages (http://stackoverflow.com/help) and then edit your question accordingly. You do not need to comment, if you can edit your own post.

Comment: Really? TextBox13-22? Button6? Variables s and a? A `MsgBox` tagged with asp.net? No sql parameters or validation? Is this a deliberate attempt for thedailywtf?

Comment: Don't use direct concatination of input controls such as textbox use parameters for this

Comment: How is your variable 'a' defined? And as Simon says, you should use sensible names for your variables.

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
update product set quantityavailable=quantityavailable - "+ s.ToString() +" where productid='" + TextBox15.Text + "'"
```

And try to read about SqlParemeters.

Comment: again show that error for Conversion from string "update product set quantityavail" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: I've changed the answer accordingly

Comment: could you paste the stacktrace? in which line it occurs?

Comment: am fine out the answer for that question.thank u so much friend.

Comment: update product set quantityavailable=quantityavailable - "& s &" where productid='" + TextBox15.Text + "'"